# msgrcv() - receiving various messages

Tags: c, ipc

In my project, the protocol (unchangeable) specifies the following structures:

```
typedef struct {
long type;
char username[USER_NAME_MAX_LENGTH];
int ipc_num;
}MSG_LOGIN;


typedef struct{
long type;
int msg_type;
char send_time[6];
char sender[USER_NAME_MAX_LENGTH];
char receiver[USER_NAME_MAX_LENGTH];
char message[MAX_MSG_LENGTH];
}MSG_CHAT_MESSAGE;

typedef struct{
long type;
int request_type;
char user_name[USER_NAME_MAX_LENGTH];
}MSG_REQUEST;
```

The client can send any of those structures to the server, and the server has to react accordingly. I'm writing a server, and have no idea how to use `msgrcv()` to receive them. When I have only one such structure, it's easy - I just pass a pointer to an empty structure of such type to it. But what if I don't know in advance which one I'll receive? Should I just define `struct generic {long type; char buffer[BIG_NUMBER];}`? If so, will I be able to extract the data to individual variables?

Comment: What mechanism are you using for the IPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [linux man page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/msgrcv.2.html) for msgrcv() states that you have to use a generic structue

```
struct msgbuf {
    long mtype;                             /* message type, must be > 0 */
    char username[USER_NAME_MAX_LENGTH];    /* message data */
};
```

I can't think of any possible way to avoid using the generic structure . But I am sure your client/server can be modified to use the generic structure , by splitting your existing structure into multiple other generic structures

For example , consider struct **MSG_LOGIN**, some modification, i can suggest is

```
typedef struct {
long mtype;
char username[USER_NAME_MAX_LENGTH];
int ipc_num;
}MSG_LOGIN_UNAME;

typedef struct {
long mtype;
int ipc_num;
}MSG_LOGIN_IPC_NUM;
```

when you recieve the message using msgrcv() , based on type specified , you can handle the various structures in different ways , or you can collect them back int the structure you were planning to send.

For example , after you receive struct MSG_LOGIN_UNAME and struct MSG_LOGIN_IPC_NUM , you can reassemble them at the receiving end into the original **MSG_LOGIN** structure.

**Another Possible Solution** :

You can use nested structures , where all types of data structures you use, will into one structure , along with the type field , and upon receiving , access specific structures based on type.

Comment: Please do not post links to die net — it is neither up to date nor official source of information for Linux man pages. Consider using kernel.org instead.